# How to properly update user information in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I have a code that is a form, basically is suppose to update the user information.
According to Firebase documentation [manage user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile) but for some reason I'm getting this errors

[image]

This is what I have I don't think I'm missing anything is pretty much the same
The only difference is that on my firebase.js I made new cons to make codes shorter but that shouldn't affect at all.

**firebase.js**

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const storage = firebase.storage();

export {db, auth, storage};
```

**Code**

```
import {auth} from "./firebase"

const authUser = auth.currentUser
    const update = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        authUser.updateProfile({
                displayName: {fullName}
        })
    }
```

I just wanted to test it on the user name first and then do all the others but I don't understand why is not working is super simple.

**Update**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`authUser` is `undefined`. This means that `auth.currentUser` was undefined at the time when it was assigned to `authUser`. This probably means that the user is not logged in. You will need to handle the case when the user is not logged in, like

```
import {auth} from "./firebase"

const authUser = auth.currentUser
    const update = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        if (authUser) {
            authUser.updateProfile({
                displayName: fullName
            })
        } else {
            //User is not logged in, handle that case here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Got new errors at least it doesn't crash now, gonna upload pictures

Comment: should be `displayName: fullName`. atm it is `displayName: {fullName: fullName}`

Comment: Yeah I changed it and it worked, just edit answer as mentioned above

Comment: @Sysix thanks for pointing that out, edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Something I really don't understand and honestly don't wanna ask a question for it because is practically the same is why it doesn't work for email isn't it the same but just change it to updateEmail and instead of displayName use email ???

Answer (score 0):

```
import {auth} from "./firebase";
const authUser = auth.currentUser;
const update = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    authUser?.updateProfile({
        displayName: fullName
    });
}
```

Comment: Attempted import error: 'updateProfile' is not exported from 'firebase/auth'.

Comment: I have made an edit, i think it should fix your issue.

Comment: `TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.auth.updateProfile is not a function`

Comment: what version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: How can I check that ?

Comment: If you're using npm you can use `npm list firebase`

Comment: -- firebase@8.10.0

Comment: Okay. I was using the 9.0 way, I have updated the answer to reflect that.